# Numpy.allclose - Determine Tolerance Based on Similarity Percent of Binary Values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, binary

This script determines whether 2 numpy arrays `arr1` and `arr2` are identical. The arrays will only contain values 1 or 0, and will be the same size.

The arrays will always have 4 columns, but there can be a variable amount of rows, so the possible array sizes will be 4x4, 4x5, 4x6, etc (but remember, all compared arrays will be the same size).

I would like to define `min_similarity_percent` and have the "tolerance" be calculated based on this percent as well as the array size. I don't understand if I'm supposed to use the `atol` or `rtol` arguments in my case.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html

For example, if `min_similarity_percent == 90` and there is only one different element between `arr1` and `arr2` when they are both 4x4, I would like np.allclose() to return `True`, because (15/16) * 100 == 93.75, which is > 90.

How can I calculate the tolerance value `atol` or `rtol` to match this?

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([
    [0,0,1,1],
    [0,0,1,1],
    [1,0,1,1],
    [0,0,1,0]
])

arr2 = np.array([
    [1,0,1,1],
    [0,0,1,1],
    [1,0,1,1],
    [0,0,1,0]
])

min_similarity_percent = 90
similar = np.allclose(arr1, arr2)

if similar:
    print("similar")
else:
    print("not similar")
```

Comment: The element differences will be 0 or 1. `allclose` tests each element, not some sort of mean.  It's meant for comparing floats, which may close without satisfying the `==` test.

Comment: Thanks for the info. In that case I probably need to use numpy.sum on both arrays and calculate the % difference, then compare it to my minimum. I wonder if there's a faster way, or if that's about the optimal way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, comparison routines between arrays are **element-wise**. If you want to compare the whole array, you need to tell numpy how you are going to calculate the "metric" between both arrays. Assuming you are using the mean, simply do:

```
tol = 90 / 100
(arr1 == arr2).mean() >= tol
```

The `.mean` method by default will sum booleans as `0s` and `1s` and return a float.